# Unable to make it work for multiple S3 buckets AWS Serverless Image Handler

Tags: amazon-web-services

We start using AWS serverless image handler https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/overview.html and deploy the solution successfully. Our images reside in 3 different S3 buckets and we provided comma separated S3 bucket name in CloudFormation template like bucket1, bucket2, bucket3

We are only able to access from 1st bucket like following https://sample.cloudfront.net/300x0/test.jpg

based on documentation, if we use url like following, it don't return us image. https://sample.cloudfront.net/300x0/bucket1/test.jpg

We aren't sure if we need to update anything in cloudformation or something is missing. We are using latest version V6.2.1.

Will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Please post CF code etc

Comment: @cyberwombat - I am unable to attach CF code here as it passes the character limit for question but it is same default CF template from https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/serverless-image-handler/latest/serverless-image-handler.template

Answer (score 0):

The Serverless Image Handler accepts two types of requests:
Legacy style (Thumbor requests) include modifications to the URL like in your post, and as mentioned in the Implementation Guide:

Legacy requests (Thumbor and custom) are limited to sourcing images from the root level of
S3 buckets and sourcing original images from the first bucket only in the SOURCE_BUCKETS
environment variable. You can adjust this in the environment variables section of your image
handler Lambda function. For example: SOURCE_BUCKETS: "my-bucket-001, mybucket-002, my-bucket-003".
In order to customize which bucket you'd like to pull from, you must use the base64 encoded JSON style requests (Define the request as a JSON dictionary, then base64 encode that dictionary and append it to the end of your URL), you can see some examples of this here.